# How to change a final variable with a Deep-Copy-Constructor?

Tags: java, copy, copy-constructor, final, serial-number

I have to create a deep copy constructor of a Movie which should have the same serial like the committed Object. 
The first steps I think are already correct but when I try:
"this.serial = that.serial" it gives a warning and says I can't override **final** variables.

I could solve this problem when I remove the **final** keyword, but that is not allowed.
Can anyone help me to change the **final int serial** variable without removing the final keyword?

```
private int serial;
private String title;
private FSK fsk;
private boolean isRent;

private final int serial;
private static int nextSerial;

Movie(String title, FSK fsk) {
    this.title = title; 
    this.fsk = fsk;
    this.serial = nextSerial;
    nextSerial++;

}
Movie(Movie that) {
    this(new String(that.title), that.fsk);
    this.serial = that.serial;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call the other constructor: `this(new String(that.title), that.fsk);`

You are getting this error because this.serial is getting set in the other constructor you call.  Once a final variable is set, you cannot set it again.  That is why you're getting the error.

Comment: It is an exercise for my class and they want: "Implement a Copy-Constructor for a Movie which copys all Object-variables (serial too).

Comment: "Implement a Copy-Constructor for a Movie which copys all Object-variables (serial too)."

Comment: Yes, just do 'this = that' for each field.  The reason it wasn't working for the serial field is because it is final (as stated above).

Comment: Also, not sure what is stored in the FSK object, but you may need to make of copy of that object as well depending on what its purpose is.

Comment: Ahhhh okey, but then i've following question: when I write:
this.title = that.title; is the constructor creating a copy of the committed Object or is he just using the same reference? 
Would it be correct when it write: this.title = newString(that.title);

Comment: @user2517208: It's just using the same reference, but as strings are immutable it doesn't matter. There's no point (or at least very little point - there *are* edge cases) making copies of immutable objects.

Comment: If you wanted a new copy of the String object, then yes, you would want to do new String.  Most cases this = that for String is fine though, as @JonSkeet stated.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'd like to give both of you a checked but it is unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by aglassman, you would end up setting `serial` twice - once in the chained constructor, and again in the one which calls it. You're not allowed to do that. (You also don't want to increment `nextSerial`, I suspect.)

I suggest you create *one* constructor which sets all the fields - then call it from the other constructors. For example:

```
Movie(String title, FSK fsk) {
    // Note: Change nextSerial to an AtomicInteger
    this(title, fsk, nextSerial.incrementAndGet());
}

Movie(Movie that) {
    this(that.title, that.fsk, that.serial);
}

private Movie(String title, FSK fsk, int serial) {
    this.title = title;
    this.fsk = fsk;
    this.serial = serial;
}
```

Note that there's no need to use `new String(that.title)` as strings are already immutable. Also I've changed your use of `nextSerial` to use an `AtomicInteger`, as otherwise you'll have thread safety issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a field and then define it again.

```
private int serial;
...
private final int serial;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be al little pawky here, but please hold on before downvoting and read whole response ;)
First of all it's not true that you can't change final field. In Java you can do almost everything ;) Check this out:

```
    public class Movie {

    static class FSK { /* TODO */ }

    private String title;
    private FSK fsk; 
    private boolean isRent;
    private final int serial;
    private static int nextSerial;

    Movie(String title, FSK fsk) {
        this.title = title;
        this.fsk = fsk;
        this.serial = nextSerial;
        nextSerial++;

    }

    Movie(Movie that) {
        this(new String(that.title), that.fsk);
        setFinalSerial(that.serial);
    }

    void setFinalSerial(int newValue) {
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField("serial");
            field.setAccessible(true);

            java.lang.reflect.Field modifiersField = java.lang.reflect.Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
            modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~java.lang.reflect.Modifier.FINAL);

            field.set(this, newValue);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

        /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Movie m1 = new Movie("title", new FSK());
       Movie m2 = new Movie(m1);
       System.out.println(m1.serial);
       System.out.println(m2.serial);
    }
}
```

But this is only an ugly trick. I guess that your class should look like this:

```
    public class Movie {

    static class FSK { /* TODO */ }

    private String title;
    private FSK fsk; 
    private boolean isRent;
    private final int serial;
    private static int nextSerial;

    Movie(int serial, String title, FSK fsk) {
        this.title = title;
        this.fsk = fsk;
        this.serial = serial;
    }

    Movie(String title, FSK fsk) {
        this (nextSerial++, title, fsk);
    }

    Movie(Movie that) {
        this(that.serial, that.title, that.fsk);
    }

        /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Movie m1 = new Movie("title", new FSK());
       Movie m2 = new Movie(m1);
       System.out.println(m1.serial);
       System.out.println(m2.serial);
    }
}
```

The point is that you should create "copy constructor" in which you can set final variable without tricks.